# Understanding Independence of First Integrals in Solving PDEs with Method of Characteristics

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm currently working on solving a partial differential equation (PDE) using the method of characteristics and have encountered a conceptual challenge regarding the independence of first integrals (constant solutions). The PDE in question is:

$$u_x(x+z) + u_y \cdot y + u_z(z+ y^2) = 0$$
To solve this, I've derived a system of characteristic equations as follows:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x+z, \quad \frac{dy}{dt} = y, \quad \frac{dz}{dt} = z + y^2$$
My main question is: How do we determine that the constant solutions (first integrals) found from this system are independent? Specifically:

What criteria or method should be used to assess the independence of first integrals derived from the characteristic equations?

In practical terms, is dividing one characteristic equation by another (e.g., dividing the second equation by the first) a valid approach to finding independent first integrals? If so, how can we ensure that the solutions obtained are indeed independent?

Are there specific operations (like division, summation, etc.) that are preferred or to be avoided in the process of finding these integrals, or is the choice of operation highly dependent on the specifics of the PDE and its characteristic system?

I'm also curious about the general approach to ensuring that the first integrals obtained are not only meaningful but also independent of each other. Any insights or examples of how to navigate this part of solving PDEs using the first integral method would be greatly appreciated.